# How to sync Hangouts conversations and Hangouts chat rooms?

Tags: google-hangouts

> For the purpose of this question, Hangouts chat means the interface that you access using the URL chat.google.com, while Hangouts conversation means the interface that you access using hangouts.google.com

To give more background, I have a python script to fetch data from a 3rd party API Endpoint. I then extract the required data and I want this data to be posted in one of my Hangouts group conversations.

The problem I'm facing is that, I have managed to send the Message to **Hangouts Chat Room(chat.google.com)** by configuring an incoming webhook for that room. However the room that I had created in Hangouts chats is not visible in my **Hangouts Conversations(hangouts.google.com)**.

I sent messages to individual persons via Hangouts chat and hangouts conversations, I'm able to see them on both(both seem to sync and are visible on each other). However When I create a group conversation in Hangouts Conversations or when I create a room in Hangouts chat, I'm not able to see them on each other(the sync doesn't seem to work).

I also read a bit about bots in hangouts, which seems to be a bit more complex implementation rather than just a post call from a python script.

So I would like to know how can I post a message to my hangouts group conversation(hangouts.google.com), is the Bot implementation the only way to do it? Or is there a way to sync chat.google.com and hangouts.google.com?

---

Edit_1: To give more context It seems like Hangouts chat is a message collaboration tool similar to Slack and Hangouts conversations seems to be a private instant messaging tool.

Also to give more context on sync between hangouts chat and hangouts conversations: I had mentioned the private messages get synced and show up on each other, however inside Hangouts chat in a one-on-one conversation if I use an incoming webhook those messages are not synced with Hangouts conversations and do not show up.

It would be great if someone could elaborate on the above questions or if suggest a way to show Hangouts chat inside a Gmail window. Since my team extensively uses Hangouts conversations, I'd like to see somehow they receive the messages sent via API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hangouts Conversation you are referring to seems to be Hangouts Classic. At the moment, there is no way to sync the two since Hangouts Chat has newer and more complex features that Hangouts Classic does not support. However, Google is looking at making some Hangouts Chat features compatible for Hangout Classic later on.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/7651799?hl=en

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer cyntht. The one thing that I still don't understand is that google is already allowing a Private messages sync between hangouts chat and hangouts classic, however this doesn't workout when it comes to groups and rooms, may be this is because hangouts chat has some advanced features such as allowing specific bots etc

Comment: Yes, they are syncing direct messages between hangouts chat and hangouts classic and this is not available for rooms or bot features yet

Comment: Yeah, it's really weird and a bit annoying since you can have groups in both. I can't wait until it's completely replaced